# input-group-addon doesnt stick to control

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for layout. I have set max-width on the input control to 280px. But this causing `input-group-addon` not render properly when i use bootstrap's grid column size larger than 280px. `input-group-addon` does not stick with the control.

I have [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pu71kkk/) here

I guess `input-group-addon` always renders to the right of the column so there is a space between input control and addon.

How do i fix this without messing with `max-width` and `col`.

Answer (score 1):

In your *fiddle* an `.input-group-addon` has width 32px, and both of `.form-control` (`max-width: 280px;`)and `.input-group-addon` (`width: 32px`) are included in the `.input-group`, then you just need to define max-width for `.input-group`:

```
.input-group {
  max-width: 312px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3svtbcwa/)

Answer (score 0):

I would **NOT** recommend to set the `width` of `max-width` of your inputs (or any other element), within Bootstrap.

Bootstrap elements are designed to fill all the available space. They can be made responsive very easily by using the built-in grid system. My recommendation is to limit their width by limiting the width of their container, like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"><!-- NOTE THE 'XS' HERE -->
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName" type="text" value="399035034">
      <span class="input-group-addon">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v85wzajr/2/